# Could we declare a pointer of the class's type in the class declaration?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I know that is possible for a struct:

```
struct A{
    A* p;
};
```

But could we do that to a class:

```
class B{
    B*p;
}
```

I tried to google it, but end not found it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour and Dani: Just trying it out works badly in C and C++, because of the large number of things which invoke undefined behavior (and are hence broken), yet appear to work fine in most (especially naive) experiments. That is not to say this is a good question, but it should not be resolved by simply trying it.

Comment: There is a difference in the two declarations. A* is public and B* is private

Comment: @Dani: Finding out the properties according to the standard of C++ by throwing code at a compiler and seeing what sticks is often quite dangerous.

Comment: Oh Thank you very much for reminding. I forgot to try the code. Very sorry about that.

Comment: @delnan this is basic question and it is not asking is this valid or something similar but does it work, which seems off-topic but I commented in case I was missing something.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour "Works" encompasses (or at least *should* encompass) "has defined behavior"; code with UB is worse than a compiler error or consistently-wrong output as it breaks unexpectedly and in very confusing ways.

Comment: Note that you have class *definitions* there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There is no difference between a class declared with `struct` and one declared with `class` other than the default access for members and bases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a class can contain pointers to a class of the same type, and the symbol representing the class can appear in signatures of functions or in the bodies of functions defined in that class. Furthermore, it should be noted that, in C++, `struct` and `class` are identical with only one difference -- the default access level for a struct is "public", while the default access level for a class is "private" (of course, one can trivially write "public:" or "private:" at the beginning of either in order to change the access level; it is only convention that results in "class" being used for types that include more functionality, encapsulation and "struct" for pure data objects).